# how may I access the option values withing an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks like

```
    options = {
        offers : $$("div.sonan"),
        prev :   offers[0],
        next :  offers[1]
    }
```

where the property `prev` represent the first element of `offers` array and `next` represent
the second element of `offers` array.

How may I use `offers` property within the `options` object

Comment: offers have the index 0 : `options['offers']` or `options[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
document.write(option[1])
```

Change the number at the end to change objects.

option : array name.

offers : object 0.

prev : object 1.

next : object 2.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are defining the array inside the object definition and using that array to fetch elements to define other properties of the options object.
this approach won't work because while parsing the options object first, javascript doesn't know what is offers that is offfers is undefined unless the options object gets parsed.

you can see the below written code for more help.

```
// define the object
var offs = [1,2,3];
var options = {
    offers : offs,
    prev :   offs[0],
    next :  offs[1]
};
//fetch values from object
options.offers;   // should give u [1,2,3]
```